# Linux C stat() octal permissions masks, concatenate to send to function?

Tags: c, mkdir, stat

Just starting to learn some basic C and messing around with the stat() system call on Linux.

So `st_mode` returned in the struct from stat() is a bitfield. And I can get the octal permissions by simply `printf("octal %o", st.st_mode)` but I'm only interested in certain flags in the bitfield, namely `S_IRWXU, S_IRWXG and S_IRWXO` to send that value to another function, eg: mkdir.

Here's my sample program.
Ignore the fact that this is a rubbish program with the directories hard-coded, not passed as an argument to the `create_dir()` function and with no error checking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

static int create_dir(mode_t mode) {
  mkdir("/home/user/blahnew", mode);
}

main() {
  struct stat st;
  int res;
  res = stat("/home/user/blah", &st);

  printf("user %o\n", st.st_mode & S_IRWXU);
  printf("group %o\n", st.st_mode & S_IRWXG);
  printf("other %o\n", st.st_mode & S_IRWXO);

  create_dir(mode);

  return 0;
}
```

How can I take only the above flages in st.st_mode and pass it as an octal to `create_dir()` to be used by an `mkdir()` function?

If I just did `create_dir(st.st_mode)` would that not also pass all the other flags that `mkdir()` doesn't need... uid, gid, sticky bit etc?

Cheers, B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already did 99% of the work in your code.  When you say

```
st.st_mode & S_IRWXU
```

only the bits in `st.st_mode` that are present in the `S_IRWXU` bitmask remain.  So what you want is a different bitmask that combines the other three:

```
st.st_mode & (S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO)
```

Comment: Bang! That's what I was missing, a way to join the bitmask flags. I knew there had to be a way and that's easier than I thought! THANKS!

Comment: Glad to help.  You can see how the bitwise OR will set any bits that are present in the other masks.  If this answers your question, could you mark this as accepted?

Comment: Done. You answered so fast that I had to wait a few mins before accepting!